# What does ="" Symbol mean in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I came across this code and `=""` symbol was used quite abundantly in it.

```
for(var i=0; i<letterarray.length; i++){="" regexparray.push(new="" regexp(letterarray[i],"ig"));="" }="" for(var="" x="0;" x<letterarray.length;="" x++)="" {="" if(="" string.match(regexparray[x]).length=""> 1 && !repeat.match(letterArray[x]) ) {
console.log(letterArray[x] + " = " + string.match(regexpArray[x]).length);
repeat += letterArray[x];
```

Comment: It means `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '='`

Comment: I believe the code is missing some pieces, besides that `=` is an [assignment operator](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp) common to most of the languages and `" "` is not an operator, it is an empty string value.

Comment: Where exactly did you find that code? It looks a bit like a mis-encoded linebreak.

Comment: something is wrong with this code as i could not get what the person is trying to do